# katzer background mode "iOS 9" EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: cordova, ios9

after the update to "iOS 9" the background mode is not working anymore -.-

I get two warnings while compiling:

```
de.appplant.cordova.plugin.background-mode/APPBackgroundMode.m:52:10: Address of 'UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification' will always evaluate to 'true'

de.appplant.cordova.plugin.background-mode/APPBackgroundMode.m:52:58: Address of 'UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification' will always evaluate to 'true'
```

after app is in background (1 - 2 sec) it crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

```
Thread 18Queue : com.apple.root.user-initiated-qos.overcommit (concurrent)
#0 0x0000000112515081 in WebCore::SecurityOriginHash::hash(WebCore::SecurityOrigin) ()
#1 0x00000001126e4498 in std::__1::enable_if >::value, WTF::HashMap<WTF::String, WTF::HashSet<WebCore::Database, WTF::PtrHashWebCore::Database*, WTF::HashTraitsWebCore::Database* >, WTF::StringHash, WTF::HashTraitsWTF::String, WTF::HashTraits<WTF::HashSet<WebCore::Database, WTF::PtrHashWebCore::Database*, WTF::HashTraitsWebCore::Database* >> >>::type WTF::HashMapWTF::RefPtr<WebCore::SecurityOrigin, WTF::HashMap, WTF::HashTraitsWebCore::Database* >, WTF::StringHash, WTF::HashTraitsWTF::String, WTF::HashTraits<WTF::HashSet<WebCore::Database, WTF::PtrHashWebCore::Database*, WTF::HashTraitsWebCore::Database* >> >, WebCore::SecurityOriginHash, WTF::HashTraitsWTF::RefPtr<WebCore::SecurityOrigin >, WTF::HashTraits, WTF::HashTraitsWebCore::Database* >, WTF::StringHash, WTF::HashTraitsWTF::String, WTF::HashTraits<WTF::HashSet<WebCore::Database, WTF::PtrHashWebCore::Database*, WTF::HashTraitsWebCore::Database* >> >> >::inlineGetWTF::RefPtr<WebCore::SecurityOrigin >(WTF::GetPtrHelperWTF::RefPtr<WebCore::SecurityOrigin >::PtrType) const ()
#2 0x00000001126e051e in WebCore::DatabaseTracker::removeOpenDatabase(WebCore::Database*) ()
#3 0x00000001126d3cfe in WebCore::DatabaseBackendBase::closeDatabase() ()
#4 0x00000001126cfd63 in WebCore::Database::close() ()
#5 0x00000001126deaf8 in WebCore::DatabaseTracker::closeAllDatabases() ()
#6 0x000000011233ecc1 in __69+[WebDatabaseManager(WebDatabaseManagerInternal) startBackgroundTask]_block_invoke ()
#7 0x000000010da9fc1a in ___addBackgroundTask_block_invoke_2 ()
#8 0x00000001167a3ccf in __60-[BKSProcessAssertion _clientQueue_notifyAssertionAcquired:]_block_invoke ()
#9 0x00000001107beef9 in _dispatch_call_block_and_release ()
#10 0x00000001107df49b in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#11 0x00000001107c7c8b in _dispatch_root_queue_drain ()
#12 0x00000001107c7561 in _dispatch_worker_thread3 ()
#13 0x0000000110b10a9d in _pthread_wqthread ()
#14 0x0000000110b0e3dd in start_wqthread ()
Enqueued from com.apple.assertiond.processassertionconnection (Thread 21)Queue : com.apple.assertiond.processassertionconnection (serial)
#0 0x00000001107c2e6e in dispatch_async ()
#1 0x00000001167a3cb0 in -BKSProcessAssertion _clientQueue_notifyAssertionAcquired:
#2 0x00000001107beef9 in _dispatch_call_block_and_release ()
#3 0x00000001107df49b in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#4 0x00000001107c5988 in _dispatch_queue_drain ()
#5 0x00000001107c4ea9 in _dispatch_queue_invoke ()
#6 0x00000001107c7af2 in _dispatch_root_queue_drain ()
#7 0x00000001107c7561 in _dispatch_worker_thread3 ()
#8 0x0000000110b10a9d in _pthread_wqthread ()
#9 0x0000000110b0e3dd in start_wqthread ()
Enqueued from com.apple.assertiond.processassertionconnection (Thread 21)Queue : com.apple.assertiond.processassertionconnection (serial)
#0 0x00000001107c2174 in _dispatch_barrier_async_f ()
#1 0x00000001167a47d3 in -BKSProcessAssertionClient _dispatchClientCalloutBlock:
#2 0x00000001167a40da in __69-[BKSProcessAssertionClient sendCreateAssertion:withResponseHandler:]_block_invoke ()
#3 0x0000000110d6e12b in __75-[BSBaseXPCClient _sendMessage:withReplyHandler:waitForReply:waitDuration:]_block_invoke79 ()
#4 0x0000000110d6ff87 in __33-[BSXPCMessage sendToConnection:]_block_invoke ()
#5 0x0000000110ad7dd5 in _xpc_connection_reply_callout ()
#6 0x0000000110ad0334 in _xpc_connection_call_reply ()
#7 0x00000001107df49b in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#8 0x00000001107c5988 in _dispatch_queue_drain ()
#9 0x00000001107c4ea9 in _dispatch_queue_invoke ()
#10 0x00000001107c7af2 in _dispatch_root_queue_drain ()
#11 0x00000001107c7561 in _dispatch_worker_thread3 ()
#12 0x0000000110b10a9d in _pthread_wqthread ()
#13 0x0000000110b0e3dd in start_wqthread ()
Enqueued from com.apple.assertiond.processassertionconnection (Thread 21)Queue : com.apple.assertiond.processassertionconnection (serial)
#0 0x00000001107c2174 in _dispatch_barrier_async_f ()
#1 0x0000000110acde1f in _xpc_connection_mach_event ()
#2 0x00000001107df4fe in _dispatch_client_callout4 ()
#3 0x00000001107cf7a3 in _dispatch_mach_msg_invoke ()
#4 0x00000001107c57fb in _dispatch_queue_drain ()
#5 0x00000001107d00fa in _dispatch_mach_invoke ()
#6 0x00000001107c57fb in _dispatch_queue_drain ()
#7 0x00000001107c4ea9 in _dispatch_queue_invoke ()
#8 0x00000001107c7af2 in _dispatch_root_queue_drain ()
#9 0x00000001107c7561 in _dispatch_worker_thread3 ()
#10 0x0000000110b10a9d in _pthread_wqthread ()
#11 0x0000000110b0e3dd in start_wqthread ()
```

I dont know how to start debugging -.-

Comment: This is not a general issue with cordova or phonegap. This is something, what has to be discussed as an issue inside katzers plugin.

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode

Comment: i already started an issue [link](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode/issues/115)

Comment: only simulator issue Sry ... cant test with real device until yesterday

Comment: I believe I've been seeing this on the real device.